# Delegating readers Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

How do I delegate a reader that extends `FlatFileItemReader` to another reader that implements the `ItemReader<I>`? My main purpose is to use the `peek` function within the second reader to identify group changes in the file that has been read by the first reader. In the second reader I have defined a `SingleItemPeekableItemReader`.

Comment: You may wanna do it in the item processor. How can u have composite item reader? doesnt make sense.

Comment: Thanks @Elbek.I think it can be done in the reader based on previous answers on this site.I think one way to do so is to pass the FlatfileItemReader as a delegate.